# Most efficent method for getting 10th item from a singlurary linked list

Tags: c#

What is the most efficient method for getting the 10th item form the end of a list

I was thinking something like:

```
List[List.Count() - 10];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `List<T>` from `System.Collections.Generic` then you're not actually using singly linked list. It's backed by an array, and you can simple access it by index, as you already suggested:

```
list[list.Count - 10];
```

it will be *O(1)* operation. You should probably check if list has at least 10 elements before doing it so you don't get an exception.

However, if you have your own singly linked list structure you'll have to iterate the entire list to get Nth item from the end of the list. You can use the same approach, but that will force two round trips over the collection - first to get total number of elements and second to get Nth last element.

You can make it happen with just one iteration, if you store last `N` items you've seen, e.g. in a queue. This will be *O(n)* operation.

Comment: Technically, it's O(n) either way, because O(2*n) is the same as O(n). But all your points are 100% correct.